# Relation between Entity and MappedSuperClass

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Is there a way to do relation between and entity and non entity, all the entity of my projects must extends a general class and i need to make relation a certain entity and that general entity.
i tried to make the general class a mapped super class:

```
@MappedSuperClass
```

but still i cannot use it in the relation.

Comment: Changing the general class to entity is not efficient since it will require changes in all the projects.

Comment: Could you please explain your requirements to have a superclass which is an entity by itself? Maybe it could be remodeled?

Comment: I don't see a question. Can you provide more information (for example, a sample of the entities/non-entities with the relationships you are trying to create)? What isn't working? Are you getting an error?